# How can rotate the children when hover on it's parent of parent via css?

Tags: css

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#s1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></span> Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span> Submenu a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span> Submenu b</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to rotate the icon which defines in span when mouseover the li element in submenu.
my CSS code is:

```
.submenu > li :hover  a > span{
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(85deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(85deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(85deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(85deg);
    transform: rotateY(85deg);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find working sample below:

http://jsfiddle.net/WK3Q6/403/

It should be:

```
.submenu > li:hover a span{
```

Instead of:

```
.submenu > li :hover  a > span{
```

I've also removed 'hidden' class from the elements so  we can see the animation.

Thanks,
Adam